# Making shapefiles converted from .KML appear in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, google-earth, kmz

I have created shapefiles from Google Earth but they do not show in QGIS, whereas in ArcGIS Desktop they do. I have made sure they are at the top of the layers, not transparent and also I have changed their symbol colour. None of this has helped. I have also clicked 'Zoom to layer extent' and it zooms to where the layer should be. It is as if it is there, but not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You have not said how you converted the KML to shapefiles. Maybe something has gone wrong in that step. KML has some features that shapefiles don't allow and QGIS can not work with (like MultiGeometry), which might lead to an empty layer. You can activate the feature counter or look up in the attribute table if there are entries at all.

Furthermore, you can look up the extent with Rightclick -> Properties, metadata tab. If the extent does not fit to the CRS, you will not see anything. Some projections don't like the North or South pole included in the data as well.